# Calculate Days Between Based on 3 Variables & Syntax Error

Tags: sql, syntax, teradata

I'm hoping you can provide some insights on a couple of issues:

ISSUE 1 - i'm receiving the following error message running in Teradata:
"Syntax error, expected something like ')' between an integer and the 'then' keyword."

There are some duplicate records in my data and what I am trying to say is if all conditions are met, then Age in Days equals 1, otherwise, calculate the days.

ISSUE 2 - the date_diff is not calculating correctly (see table)

| Date_Phase_Modified | Historical_Phases | Date_Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/4/2021 20:33 | Closed | shows 0 - want to see 1 |
| 1/4/2021 20:32 | Implement | 63 - this is correct |
| 12/1/2020 18:34 | Implement | shows 29 - want to see 0 |
| 11/2/2020 18:20 | Implement | 0 - this is correct |
| 10/21/2020 20:07 | Early Stage | shows 0 - want to see 1 |
| 10/21/2020 20:06 | Early Stage | 0 - this is correct |
| 10/21/2020 19:59 | Early Stage | 0 - this is correct |

```
CASE when((
MAX(cast(Date_Phase_Modified as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY')) - MIN(cast(Date_Phase_Modified as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY')) 
            over (partition by F.oprty_key_nbr, Historical_Phases order by Historical_Phases, Date_Phase_Modified asc) Day(4)) = 0 then 1 else 
            
MAX(cast(Date_Phase_Modified as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY')) - MIN(cast(Date_Phase_Modified as date format 'MM/DD/YYYY')) 
            over (partition by F.oprty_key_nbr, Historical_Phases order by Historical_Phases, Date_Phase_Modified asc) Day(4)) 

end as Age_In_Phase,
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You mix Aggregates & Windowed Aggregates, the snippet is invalid (check the parenthesis), the FORMAT is not needed (assuming that Date_Phase_Modified is aTIMESTAMP) and the `Day(4)` is not needed. Besides that I don't get what youj're trying to calculate.

Comment: Your `MIN` function has windowing `OVER` clause but `MAX` does not. Also `ORDER BY` is not needed for `MIN`/`MAX` windowing, and you never need to repeat `PARTITION BY` fields in the `ORDER BY` even for something like `LAG`.

Comment: @dnoeth Thanks for your feedback.  As you can see I am truly a novice at SQL.  I am trying to calculate how many days this deal was in each phase of a selling cycle.

So, it was in the Early Stage phase for 1 Day.  Then it moved to the Implement phase for 63 days.  And finally Closed phase for 1 day.

Comment: @Fred Thanks for your expertise!  I will modify as per your recommendations!  As you can probably surmise, I am a true novice at SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match your expected result:

```
CASE 
  WHEN Date_Phase_Modified = -- for latest row per phase
                      Max(Date_Phase_Modified) Over (PARTITION BY F.oprty_key_nbr, Historical_Phases ) 
  THEN -- return duration of phase, but at least 1 day
       Greatest( Cast(Max(Date_Phase_Modified) Over (PARTITION BY F.oprty_key_nbr, Historical_Phases ) AS DATE)
                -Cast(Min(Date_Phase_Modified) Over (PARTITION BY F.oprty_key_nbr, Historical_Phases ) AS DATE)
               , 1) 
  ELSE 0
END AS Age_In_Phase
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  Am very close to expected result.  All works with exception of 2 lines.

|Date_Phase_Mod|Historical_Phases|Age_in_Phase|Comment|
  
|10/21/2020|Opportunity Identified|1
  
|10/21/2020|Opportunity Identified|1|should be 0|
  
|1/4/2021|Closed - Won|1|
  
|1/4/2021|Closed - Implementing|63|should be 64|
  
|12/1/2020|Closed - Implementing|0|
  
|11/2/2020|Closed - Implementing|0|

Comment: Is `Date_Phase_Modified` a DATE or a TIMESTAMP?